# How can I expand expressions like (A OR B) AND C to A AND C OR A AND B?

Tags: java, boolean-expression

I have tried `Javaluator` which helped me in evaluating the expressions like `(A OR B) AND C` . But now I only want to expand the expression `(A OR B) AND C` to `A AND C OR A AND B` can any body tell me how can I do this in Java any API or any other help?

Comment: Please write **I** when it's you and not the variable `i` :)

Comment: ((A && C) || (A && B)) ?

Comment: Why do you need a tool?  Why not just edit the code?

Comment: i need to expand it not to evaluate it.

Comment: Maybe he wants to create a tool which can expand logical expressions, and needs the visual feedback.

Comment: Are you making a calculator? Why do you need this, and in what kind of datastructure do you have the expression? Also, are you sure about (A||B)&&C is the same as (A&&C)||(A&&B)? :oP

Comment: i have a expression like this (A OR B) AND C in a string i want to expand it like e.g A AND C OR A AND B. nothing else

Comment: Second time he do the same question with the same info, the before he obtains -11.. howe is possible that now he has a answer with that value? I think that is homework...

Comment: Deckard27 this is my first question on this site ... and im sorry boss im not pro like you!

Comment: I am not a pro.... but i dont repeat a questions.. and if i repeat a questions almost i put the same result...

Comment: @user2167728 You know people can see your question history?

Comment: no i dont know this. simont!

Comment: @user2167728 If you click a username, you can see their profile - questions and answers, comments, etc. Just so you know for next time, so your "this is my first question on this site" is ... less blatantly a lie.

Comment: let me see when did i ask my first question if its not the first!

Comment: @simont its first question but asked two times.if you cant help me dont waist your time on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to do it yourself, you may use Wolfram|Alpha API, it has a plenty of boolean-algebra-related features, like converting to various normal forms and so on. If that's a homework and you should invent your own wheel, you may use some parsing tools (or invent your wheel, again) to tokenize the string and then apply the set ob boolean algebra rules: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BooleanAlgebra.html

I think I should make this more concrete - you can't solve this problem in general case without writing that set of rules in your code (hardcoding it). The most concise way is to use something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to produce a boolean-rules-constrained language and then just feed your inputs to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is called The De Morgan rules. I think the best option is to use a [Karnaugh Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_maps) to do this. This [truth table generator](http://turner.faculty.swau.edu/mathematics/materialslibrary/truth/) will help you on your way.

Comment: More generally boolean algebra. De Morgan is just a couple of equivalences related to negation AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

(A OR B) AND C to A AND C OR A AND B

This is false.... (A or B) and C is equals to  (a and c) or (B and C)........

Comment: so how can i do this in java ?

Comment: put some code, and we can try to help you, here is not a place where the people ask for code, here the people search help for their code....

Comment: @Pshemo it the second time that he ask the same question... in his first time he ask for (A or B) and C is equals to (a and c) or (B and C)........

Comment: im new here if you wont guide me how will i learn ? And infact new to programming. i am not asking some one to write all the code for me but i am asking or hints etc...

Comment: Actually in Java `(A OR B) AND C` is equal `A AND C OR B AND C` because AND has higher priority then OR. But yes, generally it is better to write it with parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

If number of variables is not very big you may test expression for every set of variables. And if it's true on set `A = true, B = false, C = true` add to result `OR (A and !B and C)`

This form is called "[Full disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)"